# How to handle 'index out of bounds error' in C++?

Tags: c++, error-handling

The following code segment produces an 'index out of bounds' error. I know the source of this error. I was wondering if there is a way to make the program display the values of indices[I],normpar[I] and normxpar[I] when the the 'index out of bounds' error is produced. That would've helped me a lot with narrowing down the source of error.

`for (I = 0; I < 100; I++) 
 norm2par[I] = (normxpar[I] - discvec[indices[I]]);`

Comment: Viewing the values is just one of the things a debugger can do.

Comment: If `norm2par`, `normxpar`, and `discvec` are objects of type `std::vector`, you can use [`std::vector.at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) inside a `try-catch` block.

Comment: Or you can just add temporary print statements inside the loop to see how far it gets.

Comment: I typically put `assert(indices[I] >= 0)` if I'm not sure of my boundaries (pun intended)

Comment: Hideously unclear question.    You know there is an out-of-bounds error - which means you know at least one of the values you listed cannot be accessed.   But you still want to display ALL those values????

Comment: Re *"produces an 'index out of bounds' error."*: How does that happen? What compiler, environment, etc.? Is it [Managed C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_C%2B%2B) ([.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework))?

Answer (score 1):

```
void foo(std::vector<int>& norm2par, 
         std::vector<int>& normxpar,
         std::vector<std::size_t>& indices,
         std::vector<int>& discvec)
{
    std::size_t I;

    try
    {
        for (I = 0; I < 100; I++) 
        {
            norm2par.at(I) = (normxpar.at(I) - discvec.at(indices.at(I)));
        }
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << __func__ << " throw with I=" << I;
        std::throw_with_nested(std::logic_error(ss.str()));
    }
}
```